# Corona SDK set image as a wallpaper?

Tags: android, coronasdk

Hei ther any ideas how to set images as a wallpaper in corona sdk for android?
I have images in my program that i want to set as phone wallpaper when someone clicks on a button

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a listener event which call to a function.

code for the background:

local background = display.newImage("start.png")

screenGroup:insert(background)